# Deweatherize time series

Tags: math, regression, forecasting

Has anyone tried to Deweatherize time series data? Deweatherize meaning removing the weather effects from the data. We are having difficulty incorporating that variable in the time series? Does anyone have any experience with how to use variable in time series? For example, economy, seasonal effects so on.

Bolger bands is one technique to solve the problem. We are still researching, but I wanted to hear from other folks.

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more specific to get a meaningful answer. All of those terms trace to http://www.planalytics.com/Content183.phtml. This is more of a question about a particular company's service than a general math question.

Comment: @Hans I have edited my comment. Let me know if I still need to be more specific. Have you had any experience with removing an effect in time series data?

Comment: What kind of time series? Do you know what mechanisms will cause the weather to affect the data? Will the effects be mostly linear or highly non-linear? Will the effects be immediate or occur with some lag, and if there is a lag, will it be a constant time span?

Comment: @McG See my answers below.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add a comment on the box. That's why I am answering here.

The time series has time dependent sales. And now we are trying to add weather in that time series.

For example: 1.06 of weather variable means we had 6% more sales than expected because of weather.

There's no lag on this weather variable since we are trying to deweatherize historical data.